# After looping through table, rails displays an array of complete table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, view

I'm trying to make a blog in Ruby on rails and I want to display the `posts` table in my view. Simple as my good looks, something manages to fail. After looping through the whole table, and rendering the records to my view, it also renders an array with the complete table to my view.
[image: the index view]

The code that creates this view is this:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper"> 
        <h1 class="title">
          <%= post.title %>
        </h1>

        <p class="date">
          Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> Ago
        </p>

        <p class="body">
          <%= post.body %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p style="color:red; font-size:1.5em;">the array is added after the div</p>
<%end%>
<p style="color:red; font-size:1.5em;">but still inside the loop</p>
<br />
<%= link_to "New post", new_post_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line should just be `<%` instead of `<%=`.

Using `<%=` renders whatever is inside into the html. For a `.each` you don't need to render the object you're using, so `<%` works fine.

Simple syntax error :)

Comment: Indeed this solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
   ...
<%end%>
```

It is because of the `<%=` sign, you have to use `<%` instead,

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   ...
<%end%>
```

Because `each` return array on which it was called, and you use `<%=` sign which will run Ruby code and display it, that's why you have at the end the Array on which you called `each`

Comment: Indeed this solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
```

to

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Comment: Indeed this solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try change this code:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
```

into this :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

This `<% @posts` sign indicate that you want to display out together the instance variable, but you only want to evaluate that.

Comment: Indeed this solved it, thank you!